# AOP advice not getting invoked

Tags: java, aop

I've defined the following AOP config in spring:

```
<aop:config>
   <aop:aspect ref="aopAdvice">
        <aop:around
            pointcut="execution(* com.bis.client.auto.ClientHandler.sendCanonical(..))"
            method="methodDuration"/>

    </aop:aspect>
    <aop:aspect ref="aopAdvice">
        <aop:around
            pointcut="execution(public * com.bis.client.auto.MessageHandlerImpl.messageArrived(..))"
            method="methodDuration"/>
    </aop:aspect>
</aop:config>
```

I basically want the methodDuration method to be called when the sendCanonical method or the message method gets called.

The issue is the advice never gets invoked, even though im 100% sure that those methods get called.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have  defined. Also make sure all other configurations are same as defined in springsource documentation.

If above things are fine then change pointcut to "execution(public * *(..))". THis cuts every public method of every class. By doing this AOP advice should be called for every public method in your app. If this works fine, that means your configurations are right. If this doesn't work, then be sure that your configurations are not fine. So modify configs & try this step.

Once above step works fine, then slowly one-by-one modify pointcut like first add class name (this should cut every public method in that class) then add method name etc.

Best of luck !!!!!